# Public event in a private Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar

I want to create an ICS-File containing some 'private' events but also some 'public' ones I'm not in charge for the dates.

Use case:
I want to add to a calendar in addition to some own appointments the dates for the waste disposal. For this a public calendar released by the company for waste disposal exists, but e.g. the summaries contain information about village / street which is superfluous for 'My' calendar. Also I want to add alarms as reminder suitable for my life style.

I export the public calendar in an ICS-File, read out of it the relevant data, modify them and write for each entry a related one with an own UID in the ICS-File for my calendar.

This works fine so far. But: Is there also a possibility to set a relation for those events to the official calendar of the company for waste disposal, means: If they change one date, the date get changed in my calendar as well, but my other attributes (Summary, Description, Reminders, …) stay the same?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: 1)an ics file is public or private.  If people have access to the ics url, they have access to all  the contents of the file, so best to have separate public & private  2) to have dates update, the ics calendar must be subscribed to, not exported & imported.   As for the rest, as the bot says, breakdown the questions more clearly.